# backtrace.dll works with gcc 8 but not gcc 12

Tags: c, gcc, mingw32

I have some C code that is used to print backtrace in console.
I am compiling it using this command:

```
set PATH = %PATH%;D:\gcc-12.1.0\mingw32\bin
D:\gcc-12.1.0\mingw32\bin\gcc -O2 -shared -Wall -ID:\gcc-12.1.0\mingw32\include backtrace.c -static -o backtrace.dll -L. -lbfd -lz -liberty -limagehlp
```

The dll compiles with both GCC 8 and GCC 12, but does not load when using GCC 12. It works with GCC 8 regardless of which version was used to compile it.

I can post the code if required.

[This is the intended behavior when running with gcc 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37j9h.png)

[Running with GCC 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COtiQ.png)

[And the abnormal ending happens on line 56](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16LZK.png)

I have tried with different flags, doesn't seem to make a difference, compilation is not the issue, only loading the dll.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know where a dll is searched in windows. But I suspect that something is wrong with the environent and the dll is simply not found

Comment: Hello Ingo, thanks for your comment. The dll is used by a eclipse extension, it's in the root folder of the extension, and is found by one compiler and not the other. So I think it has something to do with the version of the GCC but I cannot pinpoint it.